# How to calculate the wedge product $d(\cos\theta)\wedge d\varphi$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, exterior-algebra

Gravitation By Charles Misner, Kip Thorene, John Wheeler page 109.

$\displaystyle 
\varphi=\arctan\frac{y}{x},\cos\theta=\frac{z}{r}
\Rightarrow d\varphi=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2},
-d(\cos\theta)=\frac{-dz}{r}+\frac{z}{r^3}(xdx+ydy+zdz)$
and 
$*F=-ed(\cos\theta)\wedge d\varphi$ was given.(here $d$ represent the form.)

It claimed that $*F=(e/r^3)(xdy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx\wedge dy)$.

However, I've been trying for hours, even with Mathematica, but I couldn't get the right number.

Could you show me how to do this calculation please?

Comment: Is $\ast$ a Hodge star operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$-d(\cos\theta)=\frac{z(x\,dx+y\,dy)-(x^2+y^2)dz}{r^3}$$
$$(x\,dx+y\,dy)\wedge(x\,dy-y\,dx)=(x^2+y^2)dx\wedge dy$$
$$z(x\,dx+y\,dy)\wedge\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}=z\,dx\wedge dy$$
$$-(x^2+y^2)dz\wedge\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}=x\,dy\wedge dz+y\,dz\wedge dx$$
Now add the last two equations and divide by $r^3$.